# NoMethodError undefined method 'each' for "" :String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Upon attempting to update my table in rails, I am receiving the error:

`undefined method 'each' for "StringHere" :String`

This line is causing the error:

```
current_user.events = eventstring
```

I've also tried used the update method as

```
current_user.update(events: eventstring)
```

and received the same error.

Here is my StackTrace

```
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:365:in `replace'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:47:in `writer'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `events='
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:251:in `block in update'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.2.5)   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:250:in `update'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:43:in `update'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:63:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5)     lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.5)     lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call' 
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in  start_thread'
```

My 'user' model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
        user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
        user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
        user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['user.provide.capitalize']
        user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
        user.school = nil
        user.save!
        user
    end
end
has_many :userevents
    has_many :events, :through => :userevents
```

end

The 'event' model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :userevents
has_many :users, :through => :userevents
```

end

The 'userevent' model:

```
class Userevent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :event

def self.dedupe
    grouped = all.group_by{|ue| [ue.user_id, ue.event_id]}
    grouped.values.each do |dupes|
        first_one = dupes.shift
        dupes.each{|double| double.destroy}
    end
end
```

end

Please help!

Comment: What is `events` column type?

Comment: A string (I checked again)

Comment: Could you write the model?

Comment: I am just guessing, but it seems that you have two associated models User and Event. User 'has many' events. Therefore each is getting called. However in rails each doesn't work on string, hence the error.

Comment: @user3282479 yeah, there's a line stating "has_many :events, :through => :userevents"
How should I fix it?

Comment: Do not pass a string, where rails expects an 'Event' object(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined events(association) and you tried to assing string on `events` it raise error.

You can not assign string to association. if you create `events` string column on user model. you should change `events` column name or change `events` association(has_many) name. This makes conflict.